Scraping but no content although not being blocked
I have scraped the content in nhatot.com website, but there are no content available . i Think my computer was blocked but not. I can normally access to the website(nhatot.com)
Here is my python code
page = 1

header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
payload = {
    'render_js' :'true'
}
proxies = {
   'http': 'http://eiQqeQQ5:kvXXT9db@45.83.25.193:63362/' 
   # 'https': 'https://eiQqeQQ5:kvXXT9db@45.83.25.193:63362/',
}

base_url = "https://www.nhatot.com"

list_house_url=[]
for i in range(1,10):
    url = "https://www.nhatot.com/mua-ban-bat-dong-san?page="+str(i)
    print(url)
    request =requests_a.get(url,headers=header,proxies=proxies ,params=payload,verify=False)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(request.content,'html.parser')
    soup1= BeautifulSoup(soup.prettify(),'html.parser')

    page_content =  soup1.find_all('a',class_='AdItem_adItem__gDDQT')
    print(page_content)
    for a in page_content:
        list_house_url.append(base_url+a['href'])

print(list_house_url)

Here is the Result
https://www.nhatot.com/mua-ban-bat-dong-san?page=1
[]
https://www.nhatot.com/mua-ban-bat-dong-san?page=2
[]


I have try using proxy but it still work.

Your URL uses the https scheme so there's no point in your proxy specification. Also, if you check the HTTP response code (which you should always do) you'll see that it's 403

is there a text like "just a moment..." inside the request.content? can you debug it please?

yeah it has 'just a moment...' . OKay i will debug it

What is requests_a ?

I only see this " 
Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
" inside the html tag

I tap wrong 'requests_a" must be "request" i do it after run code, it does not affect the result

@LABOMOBI What is request? If you mean requests then I repeat that this code will return an HTTP 403 status code

Yeah it return 403

the website has bot protection, the response says "verify you're a human". this is why you can't get the website content

Oh how i can by pass it , suppose the website using cloudfare

@LABOMOBI you can try using paid proxy services to bypass it.
